# Route parameter in Micronaut declarative http client

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-client, micronaut-rest

I have an API gateway using the declarative Http client and trying to pass the route parameter to the other microservice application as below

```
@Client(id="feteBirdProduct", path = "/sub-category")
public interface ISubCategoryClient extends ISubCategoryOperation{
}
```

The path on the @Client `path = "/sub-category"` is this correct for this URL `http://localhost:8081/60236833af7a1d49478d2bef/sub-category`

The Api Gateway controller

```
@Controller("/api/${api.version:v1}/{categoryId}/sub-category")
public class ApiGatewaySubCategoryController implements ISubCategoryOperation{
    private final ISubCategoryClient iSubCategoryClient;

    public ApiGatewaySubCategoryController(ISubCategoryClient iSubCategoryClient) {
        this.iSubCategoryClient = iSubCategoryClient;
    }

    @Override
    public Maybe<?> get(@ValidObjectId @NotBlank String categoryId) {
        return this.iSubCategoryClient.get(categoryId);
    }
}
```

**ISubCategoryOperation**

```
@Get
    @Secured(SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS)
    Maybe<?> get(@Parameter(description="Category id") @ValidObjectId @NotNull String categoryId);
```

Implementation in the other microservice

```
@Controller("/{categoryId}/sub-category")
public class SubCategoryController implements ISubCategoryOperation {
    @Override
    public Maybe<?> get(String categoryId) {
        return iSubCategoryManager.find(categoryId);
    }
}
```

However, on the below CURL

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/60236833af7a1d49478d2bef/sub-category" -H  "accept: application/json"
```

The end point is never hit, what I am missing ?

The HTTP client logs

```
DEBUG i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Sending HTTP GET to http://localhost:8081/sub-category
```

The HTTP request should be `http://localhost:8081/60236833af7a1d49478d2bef /sub-category`

Comment: What is HTTP response message?

Comment: It goes to the fallback url however on the HTTP logs - Sending HTTP GET to http://localhost:8081 it should be Sending HTTP GET to http://localhost:8081/60236833af7a1d49478d2bef/sub-category

Comment: I believe that you need to redifine the get in your ISubCategoryClient, I believe that currently the categoryId is being passed as parameter.

Try to redefine the get on ISubCategoryClient to something like:

@Get("/{categoryId}/sub-category")
@Secured(SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS)
Maybe<?> get(String categoryId);

And remove the path from the ISubCategoryClient @Controller annotation. I believe that should do it.

Comment: @matutano It's not only for the get method , I do have same thing for post, put and delete method. I don't want to redefined again all for all the methods. Is there a better way to do ?

Comment: I am not sure, but you can try to add the annotation @PathVariable(name = "categoryId")  in the categoryId in the ISubCategoryOperation and check if it does the trick.

Comment: @PathVariable(name = "categoryId")  doesn't work

Comment: I tried @Get("/{categoryId}/sub-category") @Secured(SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS) Maybe<?> get(String categoryId). But the request is unAuthorized Received response 401 from http://localhost:8081/60236833af7a1d49478d2bef/sub-category. However, the method is denoted with @Secured(SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS)